# How to listen to a webhook on a route inside another route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, webhooks

I have an api which communicates with a third party service. This third party service uses two live server url's which it uses to asynchronously pass the actual response with of any kind of communication with the service - result and error back to my application using webhook. So I created a tunnel with ngrok and I also created two urls (http request listener i.e route) which receive the result/error from the service. Hence when I hit api 1, the actual response is passed in req.body to the listener 1 & 2. What now I need to figure out is if there is any way to pass this response from the webhook listener back to api 1, or if there is any way the async flow of my api 1 can keep going on by communicating directly with the webhook listener.

```
//Controller
const sendPaymentRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //Send payment request to 3rd party service
    const endpoint = "/mpesa/b2c/v1/paymentrequest";
    const url = MPESA_URL + endpoint;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
      },
    };
    const body = {
      Remarks: "Sending money from mobile wallet",
      QueueTimeOutURL: "http://f815c811f619.ngrok.io/api/v1/b2c/error",
      ResultURL: "http://f815c811f619.ngrok.io/api/v1/b2c/result",
    };

    const payment_reponse = await axios.post(url, body, config);
    const { data } = payment_reponse;
    console.log("Payment request => ", data); //Not the actual response


    //*------------Need actual response from the listener in routes.js--------//


    res.status(200).json({ message: "Send money request", data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while making a payment request", error);
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Error while send payment request", error: error.data });
  }
};

//Routes.js
    this.router.post("/b2c/result", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body); //Actual response from API-1
    });

    this.router.post("/b2c/error", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body); //Error if any from API-1
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can wait for the webhook call inside the api 1 block.

You could persist this request in a database, and when the payment API calls your webhook can query your database for information about the original request and process the information based on that.